# How to catch PHP Warning in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit

I am writing test cases and here is a question I have.

So say I am testing a simple function `someClass::loadValue($value)`

The normal test case is easy, but assume when passing in null or -1 the function call generates a PHP Warning, which is considered a bug.

The question is, how do I write my PHPUnit test case so that it succeeds when the functions handles null/-1 gracefully, and fail when there is a PHP Warning thrown?

Answer (score 39):

`PHPUnit_Util_ErrorHandler::handleError()` throws one of several exception types based on the error code:

- `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice` for `E_NOTICE`, `E_USER_NOTICE`, and `E_STRICT`
- `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning` for `E_WARNING` and `E_USER_WARNING`
- `PHPUnit_Framework_Error` for all others

You can catch and expect these as you would any other exception.

```
/**
 * @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning
 */
function testNegativeNumberTriggersWarning() {
    $fixture = new someClass;
    $fixture->loadValue(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I would create a separate case to test when the notice/warning is expected.

For PHPUnit v6.0+ this is the up to date syntax:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Notice;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Warning;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class YourShinyNoticeTest extends TestCase
{

    public function test_it_emits_a_warning()
    {
        $this->expectException(Warning::class);

        file_get_contents('/nonexistent_file'); // This will emit a PHP Warning, so test passes
    }


    public function test_it_emits_a_notice()
    {
        $this->expectException(Notice::class);

        $now = new \DateTime();
        $now->whatever; // Notice gets emitted here, so the test will pass
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for PHP 7.0. In any later versions there are other PHP-specific exceptions.

Comment: @sanmai I don't see that problem. The example above works with php 7.2 and PHPUnit 7.0 as well - just tested it myself.

Comment: Thanks! Also to test for specific message you need to call both of these: `$this->expectException(Warning::class); $this->expectExceptionMessage('the message');`

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me was modifying my phpunit.xml to have

```
<phpunit
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         strict="true"
         >
</phpunit>
```

The key was to use `strict="true"` to get the warnings to result in a failed test.

Comment: Note to the reader, all of these attributes fail on modern versions. Tested on PHPUnit 10.2.2.

Answer (score 3):

You can also write a phpunit.xml file (on your tests dir) with this:

```
<phpunit 
convertErrorsToExceptions="true" 
convertNoticesToExceptions="false" 
stopOnFailure="false">
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Note to the reader, all of these attributes fail on modern versions. Tested on PHPUnit 10.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Netsilik/BaseTestCase](https://github.com/Netsilik/BaseTestCase) (MIT License) you can test directly for triggered Errors/Warnings, without converting them to Exceptions:

`composer require netsilik/base-test-case`

Testing for an `E_USER_NOTICE`:

```
<?php
namespace Tests;

class MyTestCase extends \Netsilik\Testing\BaseTestCase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

        $this->_convertNoticesToExceptions  = false;
        $this->_convertWarningsToExceptions = false;
        $this->_convertErrorsToExceptions   = true;
    }

    public function test_whenNoticeTriggered_weCanTestForIt()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->bar();

        self::assertErrorTriggered(E_USER_NOTICE, 'The warning string');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function testFooBar(): void
{
    // this is required
    $this->expectWarning();
    // these are optional
    $this->expectWarningMessage('fopen(/tmp/non-existent): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory');
    $this->expectWarningMessageMatches('/No such file or directory/');

    fopen('/tmp/non-existent', 'rb');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Make SomeClass throw an error when input is invalid and tell phpUnit to expect an error.

One method is this:

```
class ExceptionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testLoadValueWithNull()
    {
        $o = new SomeClass();            
        $this->setExpectedException('InvalidArgumentException');
        $this->assertInstanceOf('InvalidArgumentException', $o::loadValue(null));
    }
}
```

See [documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions) for more methods.

Comment: This method requires altering the class under test which is probably a good idea for invalid argument values.

Comment: This approach isn't of much use for situations where you want your method to log a warning and continue.  For example if you're dividing numbers and require an integer output your class might round the result and issue an E_USER_WARNING to indicate that a rounding occurred.  If you throw an exception instead then the flow of execution will be interrupted.